# Configuring Field Mapping through XML

Tags: xml, mapping, ignite

There is a way to map fields of entity to a SQL query field's name through the `@QuerySqlField(name="")` annotation, but I couldn't find a way to define it in an XML file.
for example I have SQL: `Select NAME_, VAL_ from PropertyEntity` but `PropertyEntity` have `name` and `value` fields

I found Cache type metadata setting, but I can't find mapping.

UPD:
I found keyFields property into CacheTypeMetadata. I think it maybe what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an issue in Jira for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-1036

I think it must be fixed pretty soon.

Comment: yep, I wrote the same question on Ignite forum and they created an issue